# msbuild doesn't copy output of referenced native project to c# project out dir

Tags: build, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, devenv

I'm struggling with this for a long time now.

The setup:

- c# project
- c++ project
- c# project has a reference for the c++ project with the following lines:

  ```
  <ProjectReference Include="projectB.vcxproj">
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
      <OutputItemType>Content</OutputItemType>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </ProjectReference>
  ```

This works from withing visual-studio.
This works when using devenv from command line.
When using msbuild from command line - the output file of the c++ project is not copied over into the output directory of the c# project.

I wasn't able to fix that using msbuild. Read a lot about it, nothing worked. Tried to debug in using diag verbosity - but logs of msbuild and visual-studio are very different...
I can't turn to using devenv as the build machine doesn't have valid visual-studio.

In msbuild log with diagnostic verbosity I see:
`Target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" skipped. Previously built successfully.`
This is where in the visual-studio log - it looks different - and actually works on copying the referenced native files to the c# output directory.
Perhaps something related with build order?..

In msbuild log - I also see:
`Target "_CopyOutOfDateSourceItemsToOutputDirectoryAlways" skipped, due to false condition; ( '@(_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectoryAlways)' != '' ) was evaluated as ( '' != '' ).`
While in the visual-studio build log I see this target executed (it comes right after GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems target)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 3:**
It seems that previous solutions cause unwanted side-effects such as breaking the build when running multi-threaded builds.

Current solution, that does seem to work is to add:
`<Targets>Build;BuiltProjectOutputGroup</Targets>`
to the `ProjectReference` section.

**Update 2:**

Changing:

`Targets="%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.Targets)"`

to

`Targets="%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.Targets);GetTargetPath"`

in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`, in the MSBuild task preceded by the comment `Build referenced projects when building from the command line.` - did the trick.

However, I have no confidence in this solution, as I don't understand the entire build process. This is just a guess.

**Update 1:**

using `/p:DesignTimeBuild=true` affects dependency build order. Can't work. Continue investigation...

**Possible solution 1:**

After putting a lot of messaged into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`

I finally got to the following:
`QUIRKING FOR DEV10`

I'm still not exactly sure what that is all about, and I saw that the developers plan to remove this quirk (see https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1890).

Suddenly `DesignTimeBuild` caught my eye in the following line:

`<Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths" Condition="'%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.ReferenceOutputAssembly)'=='true' or '$(DesignTimeBuild)' == 'true'"/>`

I know that inside visual-studio this work. Googling got me to https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/wiki/MSBuild-Tips-&-Tricks.
From there the path was short to adding `/p:DesignTimeBuild=true` to the msbuild command line.

That made it work. The referenced assembly was copied over.

I don't think this should be the solution, but it works, and don't seem to break anything else (yet).

Any other suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: is there any documentation of the `BuiltProjectOutputGroup` target?